# Event Dispatch Thread painting

Tags: multithreading, swing, java-2d

Just a quick one - I'm in the process of writing a Sega Master System emulator. The design thus far is that the GUI (JFrame subclass etc.) runs in the Event Dispatch Thread, via an EventQueue.invokeLater() call, and all the emulator functions run in a separate thread. From what I understand this is supposed to be good practice, as the EDT is supposed to initialise and update the GUI, with Swing not being thread-safe.

This leads me to a small question - the console runs in the separate thread (Z80, VDP, etc.) and the VDP (when I've finished it) will update a BufferedImage. As long as I mark this BufferedImage as 'synchronized', is it safe to then access it from the EDT (the GUI's paint method in particular)? I ask this as otherwise I will have to put a lot of VDP logic into the paint method itself, and I'd rather not do this, as it will slow down the GUI overall.

Simple question I know, but I'm still getting used to pushing Java2D for decent speed animation. It is worth mentioning that right after the repaint() method is called in the logic thread, the logic thread will sleep until woken for the next frame pass, so I'm guessing there won't be a performance hit from this design - am I right?

Many thanks,
Phil Potter

*UPDATE* I should have used better language - the VDP will be accessing the BufferedImage through a synchronized setter method and the EDT will be accessing it through a synchronized getter method.

Comment: You should show us some code showing what you plan to do, because "marking a BufferedImage as synchronized" doesn't make much sense. methods or code blocks can be synchronized, but not types.

Comment: Sorry, I should have used more correct language - I meant that when the VDP updates the BufferedImage, it will do so via a synchronized 'setter' method, and when the JFrame paints it - it will do so via a synchronized 'getter' method. As the logic thread will be asleep when the painting happens in the EDT, the EDT shouldn't be waiting for a lock on the object, and hence I'm thinking this should work. The reason I'm not sure is that there is so much stuff online that says the GUI never be updated from another thread (although it's the EDT doing the painting in this case so I think I'm OK).

Comment: Why not simply pass the image from the background thread to the EDT using SwingUtilities.invokeLater()?

Comment: I thought that method only allowed for scheduling runnable tasks on the EDT? I want to paint a BufferedImage in the EDT, not run a Runnable object on the EDT. Apologies if I've misunderstood what you say.

Comment: If the Runnable's run method consists in painting the image, passing the runnable to SwingUtilities.invokeLater makes the EDT paint the image. Isn't it what you want to do?

Comment: The paint() method of my JFrame subclass (which is itself running on the EDT) is what I want to paint the image.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I see what you mean now. Your solution is identical to the one below. Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think you need to make the setter and getter synchronized since they should only be accessed from EDT.  So lets take a step back.  You said that the getter will be accessed from EDT -- so we are thread safe here.  Now with the setter method will be run on the VDP -- to handle this case we want to call invokeLater ( see example).  Take look [here](http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/uiswing/misc/threads.html) for more info.

```
Runnable updateAComponent = new Runnable() {

    public void run() { 
//this will run in the EDT
component.doSomething(); 

}

};
//this will run in the VDP
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(updateAComponent);
```

Comment: So this solution would mean when the logic thread comes to update the BufferedImage, it simply farms out the update work to the EDT? Didn't think of it this way but yes that would work I think. This would indeed mean the BufferedImage was only accessed from the EDT (even though it is instantiated by the logic thread).